# Pattern matching giving warning "Quantifier unexpected on zero-length expression"

Tags: regex, perl

I have written a regular expression for checking club member number which has valid values as 
1) `pl-XXXX` 2) `gl-XXXX` where `XXXX` is 1000-9999.

My regular expression is working fine but I am not able to understand why this below warning is been shown -

```
"Quantifier unexpected on zero-length expression in regex; marked by <-- HERE in
m/^{2}[pl,gl]+[-]{1}+[1-9]{1}+[0-9]$ <-- HERE / at test.pl line 62."
```

My code:

```
if ($count == 3){       ## check club identifier ## 
    if ($_ =~ /^{2}[pl,gl]+[-]{1}+[1-9]{1}+[0-9]$/){
    say "Line4 Good: ", $currLine;
    } else {
    say "Error in Line 4: Not a club member ";
    }
```

Comment: What is all of this `{1}+` about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the error reporting: It is pointing to the wrong place, the end of the regex. It is simply reacting to the beginning of your regex:

```
/^{2}...
```

Which is a `^` (zero length expression) followed by a quantifier (`{2}`). As demonstrated here:

```
$ perl -lwe '/^{2}/'
Quantifier unexpected on zero-length expression in regex; marked by <-- HERE in
m/^{2} <-- HERE / at -e line 1.
```

If you want to match "1) pl-XXXX 2) gl-XXXX where XXXX is 1000-9999." you probably want something like

```
/^[pg]l-\d{4}/
```

Optionally, you could exclude `0` as a valid first number, but I find that overkill:

```
/^[pg]l-[1-9]\d{3}/
```

To avoid partial matches you can either use end of the line anchor:

```
/^[pg]l-[1-9]\d{3}$/
```

Or some way to denote that the following character is not a number

```
/^[pg]l-[1-9]\d{3}(?!\d)/
```

The latter being useful in longer strings such as `foo=pl-1000,gl-2012`.

Comment: Likewise, `[-]{1}+` is wrong as well. That is two quantifiers in a row: The useless `{1}` (exactly once) and then `+` (one or more times).

Comment: @amon Yes. And `[pl,gl]+` is not very right either. I just focused on the error itself.

Comment: gl-12345 is getting validated too (as this is not limiting XXXX to four digit) I wanted to validate it till four digits only and gl-12345 should not be valid in this case

Comment: You'll have to use an end of line anchor, or some way to denote that it cannot be 5.

Comment: I assumed you knew about `$` since you used it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need this regex:

```
/^(?:pl|gl)[-]+[1-9][0-9]+$/
```

Comment: Perhaps you meant `[1-9][0-9]+`. And `-` instead of `[-]+`.